# Re-Enable Visual SVN in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I installed [Visual SVN](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualSVNLimited.VisualSVN-Subversionintegration) for `Visual Studio 2017`. It was working fine. After some days, i got a message box in visual studio to disable the `Visual SVN` for best performance. I disabled it but now, i don't know how to enable it again.

I tried installing `Visual SVN` again but it says that it is already installed. 
I checked the **Tools -> Options -> Source Control** but it has only `TFS` and `Git` options and didn't find the Visual `SVN` options.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to re-enable Visual SVN in **Tools** - **Extensions and Updates**.

Comment: Thank You @Sergey Vlasov